# T-SQL stored procedure transaction concurrency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, transactions

I have a situation where I need to wrap an update T-SQL in a stored procedure (`sp_update_queue`) inside a transaction. But I'm wondering what would happen if you have two threads using the same connection but executing different queries and one rolls back a transaction it started.

For example ThreadA called `sp_update_queue` to update table `QUEUED_TASKS` but before `sp_update_queue` commits/rollback, transaction ThreadB executes some other update or insert SQL on a different table, say `CUSTOMERS`. Then after ThreadB has finished, `sp_update_queue` happens to encounter an error and calls rollback.

Because they are both using the same connection would the rollback also rollback changes made by ThreadB?, regardless of whether ThreadB made its changes within a transaction or not.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: `select @@spid` from each "thread".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "...they are both using the same connection..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread which acquire the resource first, will lock that resource(if you have suitable isolation level), so the second thread will wait for the required resource.

Note:each thread will have their own SessionId.

**UPDATED**

In your scenario, however both of the threads are using same connection, but do not use any common resources(ThreadA is dealing with table X and ThreadB is dealing with table Y). So commit or rollback of each Thread(Thread A or B) does not impact the other one.

[Read more about Isolation Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Comment: sp_update_queue updates a table to called QUEUED_TASKS but lets say ThreadB is updating a another table (Customers) and therefore doesn't need to wait.  What would happen in this case?  I've updated my post to clarify the scenario